# Bookmarklet only works directly on source code

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a simple bookmarklet that replaces all instances of the source code of a website.
This is the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function() {document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/outer_page only_ie6_border blurred_page/g, "outer_page only_ie6_border"); }());
```

This is part of the website source code that it replaces:

```
<div class="outer_page only_ie6_border blurred_page"
id="outer_page_8"
style="width:902px; height:1297px; ">
```

The problem is, if I simply go to the website and click the bookmarklet it does not work (page flickers like it reloaded but doesn`t change). However, it works if I go to the website, open the source code (ctrl+U), click the bookmarklet, copy all the source code to a txt file, save as html and then open it.

Comment: Try to run a simple code like this: `javascript:(function( { alert(document.body.innerHTML.match(/outer_page only_ie6_border blurred_page/)); })();` What does it return? FYI: (1) some sites (e.g. 'LinkedIn' etc.) don't seem to allow to execute bookmarklets because of 'Content Security Policy'; (2) the DOM may be entirely different from the source code of your web page.

Comment: I tried your code but I had to make two changes a missing closing parenthesis after function and a "g" after the "...blurred_page/". I think I understand what you wanted to test with that code so I did multiple tests.

Running the code against the website or against the source-code directly yields the same results (an array with a bunch of legit matches). Also running it after running my bookmarklet yields null, both to the website and to the source-code.

About your LinkedIn comment, is there a way for the website to block it and at the same time be possible to open the edited html?

Comment: A missing parenthesis is my typo, sorry for that. It's unclear for me what you mean by "_at the same time be possible to open the edited html_". So far I know the only approach to edit an html on the sites like 'LinkedIn' with the help of 'iMacros for Firefox', a useful free add-on.

Comment: What I mean is, at the moment I am not able to edit the html live. However, downloading the plain-text source-code editing it and opening it on the browser works (including loading dynamic content, login in to the page etc.). How do I know if the page I'm trying to edit using the bookmarklet blocks it?

Comment: Well, in such cases you can't even run a very simple bookmarklet (for example, to alert something) - it just does nothing. Try to test this on your LinkedIn pages. Nevertheless, you should do edit the html (but not to know the possibility), so my suggestion is to apply more advanced tools for your tasks and enjoy them...